# Error importing wsdl into monodevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am having issues importing my wsdl into mono develop.

This wsdl and xsd implementation works flawlessly under Visual Studio, but cannot be imported into mono develop.

I have also checked it against several wsdl verification sites and they all pass.

The process I use is to create a project and then “add web reference”. I then select .net 2.0 as the type of wsdl. I then paste in the link to the wsdl. And then hit “jump to”.

Then I get the error listed below. This is preventing me from finishing my evaluation of the product, and any help you can provide would be beneficial.

The wsdl files are located here:
ftp.echelon.com/fae/na/outgoing/GDahl/wsdlissue/v4.0.zip

wsdl file in question is ilon100.wsdl.

```
**System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: XmlSchema error: Target namespace is required, to include a schema which has its own target namespace Related schema item SourceUri:** http://216.254.101.36/WSDL/v4.0/iLON100.wsdl, Line 31, Position 4.
  at System.Xml.Schema.ValidationHandler.RaiseValidationEvent (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handle, System.Exception innerException, System.String message, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObject xsobj, System.Object sender, System.String sourceUri, XmlSeverityType severity) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObject.error (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handle, System.String message, System.Exception innerException, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObject xsobj, System.Object sender) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObject.error (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handle, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.ProcessExternal (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler, System.Collections.Hashtable handledUris, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaExternal ext, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet col) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.AddExternalComponentsTo (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema s, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObjectCollection items, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler, System.Collections.Hashtable handledUris, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet col) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.ProcessExternal (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler, System.Collections.Hashtable handledUris, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaExternal ext, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet col) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.DoCompile (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler, System.Collections.Hashtable handledUris, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet col, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.CompileSubset (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet col, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver, System.Collections.Hashtable handledUris) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Compile (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Compile (System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler handler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemas.Find (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName name, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemas.Find (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName name, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportType (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName name, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName root, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.GetTypeData (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName root, Boolean isNullable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.GetElementTypeData (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement elem, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName root, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping& map) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportSequenceContent (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap cmap, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObjectCollection items, System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifiers classIds, Boolean multiValue, System.Boolean& isMixed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportParticleContent (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap cmap, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaParticle particle, System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifiers classIds, Boolean multiValue, System.Boolean& isMixed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportParticleComplexContent (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap cmap, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaParticle particle, System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifiers classIds, Boolean isMixed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.BuildClassMap (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping map, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeQName, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType stype) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.BuildPendingMaps () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportMembersMappingComposite (System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType stype, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName refer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaImporter.ImportMembersMapping (System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Description.SoapProtocolImporter.ImportMembersMapping (System.Web.Services.Description.Message msg, System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBodyBinding sbb, SoapBindingStyle style, Boolean output, Boolean wrapped) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Description.SoapProtocolImporter.GenerateMethod () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolImporter.ImportPortBinding (Boolean multipleBindings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolImporter.Import (System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter, System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace codeNamespace, System.Collections.ArrayList importInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImporter.Import (System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace codeNamespace, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Library.GenerateWsdlXml (System.Text.StringBuilder text, System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol protocol) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WS.WebServiceDiscoveryResultWS.GetDescriptionMarkup () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Dialogs.WebReferenceDialog.UpdateService (MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WebServiceDiscoveryResult service, System.String url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Dialogs.WebReferenceDialog+<QueryService>c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application+InvokeCB.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Timeout+TimeoutProxy.Handler () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also had occasional issues generating proxy classes based on a valid WSDL in MonoDevelop.  Firstly, I'm sure the MonoDevelop team would appreciate a bug report (see the "Reporting Bugs" section on this page: http://monodevelop.com/Developers).

In the meantime, maybe you can generate your proxy classes in Visual Studio and then import them into your MonoDevelop project.

Hope this helps!